# Spring Boot: "Field required a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' that could not be found."

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, javabeans, autowired

I have a java project that uses Spring Boot with JPA and Hibernate for database. I am trying to put together a microservice that accesses the database. (I am new to microservices and Spring Boot).

**Below is the main class:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class CircularsMicroservice {

    @Autowired
    private CircularsService circularsService;



    //microservice called here
    @RequestMapping(value="/circulars-list", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    List<GmCirculars> getAllCircularsForOrganization(@RequestBody  CircularsParams circularsParams)
    {


        List<GmCirculars> circularsList =
                circularsService.fetchAllCircularsForOrganization(circularsParams.getOrganization(), circularsParams.isActiveOnly(), circularsParams.getStartOffset());//invoke the method to get the circulars list
        return circularsList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{ 


        SpringApplication springApp= new SpringApplication(CircularsMicroservice.class);

        Map<String, Object> prop= new HashMap<String, Object>();
        prop.put("spring.application.name", "circulars-microservice");
        prop.put("server.port", "8081");
        prop.put("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class", "org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext");

        //db config
        prop.put("spring.datasource.driver-class-name", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        prop.put("spring.datasource.url", "--");
        prop.put("spring.datasource.username", "--");
        prop.put("spring.datasource.password", "--");
        prop.put("spring.jpa.show-sql", "false");
        prop.put("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto", "create-drop");
        prop.put("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");

        springApp.setDefaultProperties(prop); //configure programmatically

        springApp.run(args);
        System.out.println("done");


    }    



}
```

**IGmCircularsDAO.class:**

```
@Repository
public interface IGmCircularsDAO {


    /**
     * Save or update.
     *
     * @param obj the obj
     * @return the gm circulars
     */
    GmCirculars saveOrUpdate(GmCirculars obj);




    /**
     * Mark as deleted.
     *
     * @param rowId the row id
     * @return true, if successful
     */
    boolean markAsDeleted(BigDecimal rowId);



    /**
     * Find.
     *
     * @param obj the obj
     * @param activeOnly the active only
     * @param startOffset the start offset
     * @param maxRows the max rows
     * @return the list
     */
    List<GmCirculars> find(GmCirculars obj, boolean activeOnly, int startOffset, int maxRows);



}
```

**GMCircularsDAOImpl.class:**

```
@Repository
@Transactional
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class GmCircularsDaoImpl extends ParentDAO implements IGmCircularsDAO {

    @Override
    public GmCirculars saveOrUpdate(GmCirculars obj) {

        Session session = null;

        try {
            //session = sessionFactory.openSession(); //commented by Zaid
            session= this.getSession(); //Added by Zaid

            session.beginTransaction();
            session.saveOrUpdate(obj);
            session.flush();
            session.getTransaction().commit();

        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return obj;
    }


    @Override
    public List<GmCirculars> find(GmCirculars obj, boolean activeOnly, int startOffset, int maxRows) {
        Session session = null;
        List<GmCirculars> discounts = null;

        try {
            if (null != obj) {

                //session = sessionFactory.openSession(); //commented by Zaid
                session= this.getSession(); //Added by Zaid

                Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(GmCirculars.class);

                if (null != obj.getId() && !BigDecimal.ZERO.equals(obj.getId())) {
                    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", obj.getId()));
                }

                if (StringUtil.isNotNullOrEmpty(obj.getTitle())) {
                    criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("title", obj.getTitle(), MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
                }

                if(null != obj.getOrganization()) {
                    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("organization", obj.getOrganization()));
                }

                //commented by zaid
                /*if (null != obj.getType() && null != obj.getType().getValueId() && !BigDecimal.ZERO.equals(obj.getType().getValueId())) {
                    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("type.valueId", obj.getType().getValueId()));
                }*/


                if (null != obj.getSerialNo() && !BigDecimal.ZERO.equals(obj.getSerialNo())) {
                    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("serialNo", obj.getSerialNo()));
                }

                if (null != obj.getYear() && !BigDecimal.ZERO.equals(obj.getYear())) {
                    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("year", obj.getYear()));
                }


                if (activeOnly) {
                    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("active", BigDecimal.ONE));
                }
                else {
                    criteria.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.ne("active", CommonConstants.DELETED_STATUS), Restrictions.isNull("active"))); //Except for deleted ones -> NVL(active,2)
                }


                //LIMIT startOffset, maxRows;
                criteria.setFirstResult(startOffset);
                criteria.setMaxResults(maxRows);

                criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("id"));
                criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
                discounts = criteria.list();

            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return discounts;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean markAsDeleted(BigDecimal rowId) {

        Session session = null;
        int updatedRows = 0;
        try {

            //session = sessionFactory.openSession(); //commented by Zaid
            session= this.getSession(); //Added by Zaid

            Query query = session.createQuery("update GmCirculars set active = :statusForDel where id = :rowId");
            query.setParameter("statusForDel", CommonConstants.DELETED_STATUS);
            query.setParameter("rowId", rowId);

            updatedRows = query.executeUpdate();
            session.flush();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            session.close();
        }

        return updatedRows > 0;
    }


}
```

**ParentDAO.class**

```
@Transactional
public class ParentDAO {

    //commented by zaid
    //@Autowired
    //protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        //added by Zaid //spring boot way
        //@Autowired

        @PersistenceContext
        protected EntityManager entityManager;

        protected Session getSession() {
            return entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

        }



}
```

**CircularsService.class**

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
public class CircularsService {

    @Autowired
    private IGmCircularsDAO gmCircularDao;



    @Value("${circulars.maxRows}")
    private int circularsMaxRows;


    /**
     * Save or update.
     *
     * @param obj the obj
     * @return the gm circulars
     */
    public GmCirculars saveOrUpdate(GmCirculars obj) {
        return gmCircularDao.saveOrUpdate(obj);
    }


    /**
     * Find.
     *
     * @param obj the obj
     * @param activeOnly the active only
     * @param startOffset the start offset
     * @return the list
     */
    public List<GmCirculars> find(GmCirculars obj, boolean activeOnly, int startOffset) {
        return gmCircularDao.find(obj, activeOnly, startOffset, circularsMaxRows);
    }


    /**
     * Fetch all circulars for organization.
     *
     * @param userOrg the user org
     * @param activeOnly the active only
     * @param startOffset the start offset
     * @return the list
     */
    public List<GmCirculars> fetchAllCircularsForOrganization(Organization userOrg, boolean activeOnly, int startOffset) {

        GmCirculars criteria = new GmCirculars();
        criteria.setOrganization(userOrg);
        return gmCircularDao.find(criteria, activeOnly, startOffset, circularsMaxRows);
    }


    /**
     * Find by id.
     *
     * @param id the id
     * @return the gm circulars
     */
    public GmCirculars findById(BigDecimal id) {
        GmCirculars result = null;

        List<GmCirculars> discs = gmCircularDao.find(new GmCirculars(id), false, 0, circularsMaxRows);

        if (null != discs && !discs.isEmpty()) {
            result = discs.get(0);
        }
        return result;
    }


    /**
     * Mark as deleted.
     *
     * @param entryId the entry id
     * @return true, if successful
     */
    public boolean markAsDeleted(BigDecimal entryId) {
        return gmCircularDao.markAsDeleted(entryId);
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I am getting the following error which I have been stuck in for a while now.

```
ERROR LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field gmCircularDao in service.CircularsService required a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

How to fix? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Is right:

You're using spring data (`@Repository
public interface IGmCircularsDAO extends JpaRepository<GmCirculars, BigDecimal>`)

The whole point of spring data is to generate an implementation based on this interface in runtime. This implementation is registered as a bean that implements `IgmCircularDao` interface)

Now, right underneath you create a bean:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class GmCircularsDaoImpl extends ParentDAO implements IGmCircularsDAO {
...
```

So again, spring scans and finds this repository and tries to register it as a bean. It also implements the same interface so spring has two beans that compete with each other for the right to be injected into the service:

```
public class CircularsService {

    @Autowired
    private IGmCircularsDAO gmCircularDao; // <-- what should spring chose? an autogenerated spring data proxy or your own implementation???
...
```

Hence the exception...

You should understand do you want to maintain both repositories that implement the same interface and if so how to differentiate between them when you want to inject any of those into the services (just like in the case of `CircularService`).

You can use Qualifiers, different interfaces - there are many solutions but again, you should first understand the usage that works for you best

Comment: Thanks. I was actually adding an implementation because I was getting the error: “Field required a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' that could not be found.” I have removed the implementation now and showed the previous error in my question. Can you check my updated question please? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not a spring data expert unfortunately, I believe you shouldn't inject EntityManagerFactory but an entity manager so the exception seems suspicious if I look at your code... I've found the example of injecting an entity manager into spring data repository (note the inheritance from CrudRepository there). Hope it helps: https://www.javabullets.com/access-entitymanager-spring-data-jpa/

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with hibernate version used by spring boot 2.x Release.Adding below hibernate version resolved the issue,

```
<properties>
    <hibernate.version>5.2.14.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>
```